# Abels theorem/Integral Test to show divergence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Hi is it possible to use Abel's Theorem for series to show the following:

If $\{x_{n}\}_{1}^{\infty}$ is a positive sequence such that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_{n} = 0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_{n}$ diverges. Prove that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_{n}}{x_{n}+1}$$
diverges. I have already proved this result by other means but am interested if you can use Abel's Theorem or the Integral Test to show this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\displaystyle \lim \limits_{n \to +\infty} x_{n} = 0$ and $(x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}}$ is a sequence of positive real numbers, note that :

$$ \frac{x_n}{1+x_n} \, \mathop{\sim} \limits_{n \to +\infty} \, x_{n} $$

Therefore, the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}} \frac{x_n}{1+x_{n}}$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}} x_{n}$ have the same behavior. Since $\displaystyle \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}} x_{n}$ is divergent,$\displaystyle \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}} \frac{x_n}{1+x_{n}}$ diverges too.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am though specifically interested in knowing if we can use those two tests to show the divergence of the series.

Comment: I do not see how to apply the integral test here since it only concerns series of the form $\displaystyle \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f(n)$ where $f$ is a decreasing, non-negative function. Here, we do not know $x_n$ explicitly. Therefore, $\displaystyle \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}} \frac{x_n}{1+x_{n}}$ is not of the form $\displaystyle \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f(n)$.

Comment: Yeah I think so too. Specifically since we can't say whether it is decreasing? On a side point does it follow necessarily that if $\{x_{n}\}$ is a positive sequence such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_{n} = 0$ then $\{x_{n}\}$ is a decreasing sequence?

Comment: Not necessarily. Consider $\displaystyle x_{n} = \frac{1+\sin(n)}{n}$. $x_{n}$ is positive and $\displaystyle \lim \limits_{n \to +\infty} x_{n} = 0$ but $(x_{n})$ is not decreasing.

Comment: @jibounet I don't think it has to be given explicitly. You have $f(n) := \frac{x_{n}}{1 + x_{n}}$. I think it's more important if it satisifes the conditions of as you stated non-negative and decreasing.

Comment: @JohnDoe : The function $f$ has to be defined on an interval $I$ of $\mathbb{R}$ and continuous, in order to integrate $f$ on bounded intervals of the form $[k,k+1]$. With your definition, $f$ is only defined on $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @jibounet Yeah I think you are right. Do you know what the generally used definition of Abel's theorem is? I find [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_test).

Comment: @JohnDoe : The Abel theorem I know is this one : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem It is usually used to prove the convergence of power series (say, of convergence radius equal to $1$) at a point on the frontier of the convergence disc.

Comment: @jibounet Are you sure the integral test requires that $f$ is continuous? Check [this definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence).

Comment: @JohnJack : the page says " non-negative function f defined on the unbounded interval [N, ∞), on which it is monotone decreasing"

Comment: @jibounet Do you think a simple proof like $\sum \frac{x_{n}}{x_{n}+1} = \sum 1 - \sum \frac{1}{x_{n}+1}$ and since $\sum 1 \rightarrow \infty$ and by the term test since the sequence $\frac{1}{x_{n}+1} \rightarrow \infty$ it follows then that $\sum \frac{x_{n}}{x_{n}+1}$ diverges. What do you think?

Comment: @JohnJack : It is not true that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x_n + 1} \to +\infty$. Be careful, for example : let $u_{n} = 1$, $\displaystyle v_{n} = 1 - \frac{1}{n^2}$. Then $\displaystyle \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} u_{n}$ diverges and $\displaystyle \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} v_{n}$ diverges too but $\displaystyle \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \big( u_{n} - v_{n} \big)$ converges.

Comment: @jibounet I don't understand the counterexample you mentioned previously which you defined as $x_{n} = \frac{1+ \sin(n)}{n}\cdot x_{n}$, would you mind motivating it? Thanks for all the assistance.

Comment: My example was : $x_{n} = \frac{1+\sin(n)}{n}$ (sorry for the dot after the fraction). It was just to show that $(x_n)$ is not necessarily decreasing.